# Changing Interface Metric does not make ethernet have precedence over Wireless

Tags: windows-10, networking, wireless-networking, ethernet

So I have been trying to do this for over 2 days now and I am on the verge of giving up. Basically, I need 2 connections, the Ethernet and Wifi to be enabled at the same time. However, each time I do this, Wifi seems to take advantage over ethernet and I absolutely despise it since my ethernet is 5x faster than wifi.

I tried setting the interface metric of both ethernet and Wifi but no avail. I have no other methods as every. single. forum. post says to set the interface metric. Here is proof of my metrics:
[image]

As you can see, in both Ipv4 and Ipv6, the Ethernet Interface has a lower metric than the wifi interface, which is what the articles say to do, yet, I go over to the settings and see this:

[image]

If ethernet was being used, this should show up:
[image]

So my conclusion is that Windows is not listening at all to the Interface metrics or to anything I do for that matter, because even after the metrics have been switched to a suitable value, windows still prefers wireless over ethernet. All drivers are updated and no problems were detected with the adapters. It seems weird since I followed this post and yet over 600 people said their problem was fixed: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-networking-winpc/adapter-priority-setting-unavailable-in-windows-10/d2b63caa-e77c-4b46-88b5-eeeaee00c306.

Comment: Run TCP/IP Reset and when done try setting the Metric for Ethernet to give it priority.  Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator
(1) netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt
(2) ipconfig /flushdns
(3) restart the computer

Comment: I suggest disabling IPv6 for your internal network.

Comment: @harrymc Would that cause any complications in the future?

Comment: IPv4 is enough internally for your local network, for up to tens of thousands of devices. Externally, your router can keep IPv6 support (if enabled by your ISP).

Comment: I tend not to remove ipv6 but short term there should not be an issue.. Long term, I keep both and I do not believe ipv6 is causing the metric issue.

Comment: @harrymc It certaintly worked after I disabled IPv6, mind to add a solution so I can accept it so that future comers would find this thread useful?

Comment: @user1686: It certainly can work this way. Many routers contain more than one network adapter, one/some facing outward and one/some inward. Any outside connection is therefore actually composed of two such, with the router as intermediate with NAT. For such routers, there's no technical reason for an outside/public IPv6 connection to require an internal IPv6 connection.

Comment: @user1686: Not really, just based on circuit schema I've seen for some routers. But it's possible that this is the technology that is used internally. There will come a time when the internet will use mostly IPv6, but IPv4 will still stay with us for a very long time.

Comment: @user1686: Your understanding conflicts with mine. Let's agree to disagree.

Comment: @user1686: I don't like a fight to the end, even only figuratively. You had the last word, and let's leave it at that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution here was to disable IPv6.
For a home network IPv4 is more than enough internally,
and IPv6 may cause unforeseen behavior because by default
Windows favors IPv6 addresses over IPv4 addresses.

This is done in
*Settings > Network & Internet > Status > Change adapter options*.
Right-click the network adapter, select Properties, Networking tab
and uncheck "lnternet Protocol Version 6 (TCP/ IPv6)", then click OK.

[image]

Reference:
[Guidance for configuring IPv6 in Windows for advanced users](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/configure-ipv6-in-windows).